# What produces the most money?

Tags: adventure-capitalist

Which of these produces the most money for me to use a Mega Ticket on? (You can see I've recently been into this game a lot.).
[image]

Comment: I once saw that someone had charted it out, and the answer was - varying things at varying levels of money.  And they hadn't even considered how the angel or cash upgrades skewed the picture, just the straight shot unlocks.  I think Giant Laser won once it got to insane levels of money, but that was before the latest patch went through and changed the Moon significantly.  Bottom line, this is more complicated than your question considers it.

Comment: @Radhil, if giant lasers won out in the previous patch, that infers that the answer was previously "giant lasers". Too broad means there would be a considerable amount of answers, which unless they added considerable game changes from the last patch, would not be the cast. Sure, you would have to do more research to confirm if the answer was still "Giant Laser", but that is not what we consider to be too broad. To broad = lots of differant answers, or several pages to explain what is required to answer.

Comment: @Timelord64 - Uh, I never voted or flagged this as too broad. I did want to add information to what was a one-line question, to help the asker, but that I did not have an immediate answer to (and likely couldn't research correctly).  Apologies if that was not clear.

Comment: My apologies, @Radhil. Leaving it up, as it appears close voters are using it wrong

Answer (score 2):

Based on your screenshot, at your stage in the game, oxygen bars are the most profitable.

They will basically be your sole source of income until you get to the 2880 milestone (gonna take a while), then you will work on amusement parks, helium farms, and werewolf colonies.

Answer (score 1):

I just posted the link to the moon guide on another answer, but here's the link.

https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=443045440

If you go to the last graph, it shows after an update the investment that will make the most (long-term) is the lasers.  Second is Helium-3 farm, so I would choose either of those if you want long-term.  The graph is hard to read, since it shows the old and new lines, but another option is the oxygen bar.  Oxygen bar is short-term, but it's one of the ones with a large milestone (to hit 2880) and gives a big boost when you finally hit it.  Otherwise, just pick your biggest money makers and you'll get a slight boost.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your stage of the game and level of advancement of specific investment. If you're stuck and planning to hold more of Mega Ticket, you can use it on the current [most profitable investment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/238956/74546), but it's better to think long-term and place it on the more expensive investment such as laser.